# How can I avoid duplicate values in my result set?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, database-trigger

CREATE TABLE `student`
(
  `s_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_roll_no` int(30),
  `s_name` varchar(30),
  `s_gender` varchar(4) not null,
  `class` int(2) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`s_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `attendance_date`
(
  `date_today` varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_today`)
);

CREATE TABLE `attendance_today`
(
  `s_id` int(10),
  `s_roll_no` int(30),
  `s_name` varchar(30),
  `s_gender` varchar(4),
  `class` int(2),
  `date_today` varchar(10),
  `attendance_status` varchar(2) not null default 'P'
);

delimiter $$

create trigger after_insertion_into_attendance_date
    after insert on attendance_date
    for each row

```
begin 

insert into attendance_today(s_id, s_roll_no, s_name, s_gender, class, date_today)
select * from student cross join attendance_date order by date_today, s_id;

end$$
```

delimiter ;

INSERT INTO `student` 
VALUES 
(1,1,'Mridul Kumar','M',1),
(2,2,'Harish Paul','M',1),
(3,3,'Imtiaz Hossain','M',1);

INSERT INTO `attendance_date` 
VALUES 
('1st Jan'),
('2nd Jan');

now, 
select * from attendance_today; 
giving duplicates after every insertion, is there any way to avoid such duplicates inside trigger?
I'm not looking for 
     select distinct * from attendance_today;
after the trigger gets activated.

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent duplicate values from being inserted

```
insert into attendance_today(s_id, s_roll_no, s_name, s_gender, class, date_today)
select * 
from student cross join attendance_date ad
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT null FROM attendance_today at
    WHERE ad.s_id = at.s_id and ad.date_today = at.date_today
)
order by date_today, s_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
begin 

insert into attendance_today(s_id, s_roll_no, s_name, s_gender, class, date_today)
select * from student cross join attendance_date group by s_id order by date_today, s_id;

end$$
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work, i'm getting duplicate values grouped by dates, that means if I'm inserting values 1st Jan,2nd Jan, then I'me getting 6 values for 1st jan cause at the time of inserting 2nd jan, 1st jan is also getting inserted